# Кнопки работают на эмуляторе, но не работают на реальном устройстве

Tags: android

Столкнулся с весьма странной проблемой. У меня есть `ViewPager`, с помощью которого листаются изображения. В лэйаут с `ViewPagerом я добавил кнопку, которая закрывает данное активити и переходит на другое. На эмуляторе(Genymotion) все отлично работает, но на реальном устройстве кнопка перестает реагировать на нажатия.

Думал, что проблема в разнице версий, но это же обычный `Button`, он везде один и тот же. Так же проверял, не перекрывает ли `ViewPager` эти кнопки, но когда я поставил `wrap_content` - ситуация не изменилась.

```
public class FullActivityGallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    SlideImageAdapter adapter;
    Button exit_btn;       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);      
        initButtons();
        getMyIntent();
    }

    private void getMyIntent(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");        
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);    
        adapter = new SlideImageAdapter(this, position);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);    
    }


    private void initButtons(){    
        exit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_btn);       
        exit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FullActivityGallery.this, ActivityGallery.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

> Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >


    <Button
        android:text="exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exit_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
        >


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE: на 4.4 версии Android не работает ни на эмуляторе, ни на реальном устройстве. На 5 версии работает везде. Кто может подсказать, что именно так сильно отличается, что кнопки перестают работать?

Comment: Первое что в голову приходит: минимальная версия SDK (читай - версия Android) какая установлена?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский минимальная установлена - 15, если гугл не врёт, то это 4.0.3

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, попробуйте местами кнопку с пейджером поменять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оказалось что в 5 версии пэйджер не перекрывает кнопки, а в 4.4 перекрывает при одинаковых лэйаутах. Весьма странно, но об этом нигде не написано. Интересно, много ли еще таких момемонтов с разметками?

Comment: Поддерживаю @ЮрийСПб. Вью пейджер описан после кнопки а значит если визуально он перекрывает кнопку, то и нажатия пропускать не будет, то что работает на 5м андройде - случайность.

Comment: @Denis422, таких моментов тьма. Но можно запомнить несколько простых правил. Например в этом случае правило - то, что должно быть сверху - должно быть ниже в разметке

Comment: @xkor визуально он не перекрывает кнопку, в том то и дело

Comment: @Denis422, скорее всего он перекрывает, т.к. ViewPager плохо во wrap_content по высоте умеет. Попробуйте посмотреть что будет если включить на девайсе в настройках разработчика показ границы макета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разных версиях это может работать по разному - когда вы помещаете логически к-л элемент разметки ниже в иерархии чем другой. На некоторых версиях он будет перекрыт и не будет получать события нажатия, на некоторых же будет работать.

Правильное здесь решение - поместить логически элемент иерархии на верх, если он должен лежать поверх остальных элементов. Т.е. в вашем случае надо поменять местами кнопку и  ViewPager в разметке